# Can't see shares in a WIndows 10 PC from Explorer. No permissions when selecting PC

Tags: networking, permissions

I setup sharing on PC2 and have a shared folder, \10.10.10.2\MyShare. I am not able to see any shares if I use the Explorer to access the ip address without the share name.  I get permission denied.  But if I use the whole UNC path, \10.10.10.2\MyShare, I can see and open the folder and files in it.

In my experience, I expected to see the shares in PC2 if I explored to the computer using \10.10.10.2, much like exploring the Network from the Explorer, selecting a computer with shares and seeing the shares in the right panel.

Not to confuse things, but the computer I'm using to access PC2 is PC1.  PC1 is not able to connect to and install a LAN printer that all the other computers on the LAN can access.  I can ping it, but when I try to install it, it says Connecting but never finishes.  Could this be a problem with SMB?  I have not set SMB compatibility in the Windows Features.

Comment: SMB might not be the issue here. I suppose it could be linked to the OS on your PC. What are the Operating Systems on either PC and if it's Windows 10, do they have all the updates needed? Did you try reinstalling the network card / driver?

Comment: Do the two PCs use the same type of account, meaning both local or both Microsoft account?

Comment: The LAN is a network with 4 Windows 10 PCs.  All have current updates.  All login with  Microsoft accounts.  The shares on PC2 are setup for Everyone.  I can access the shares using the full UNC, but I can't access the PC without the share name.  I did not do anything with the network card/drivers.

Comment: I thought this might be hardware or cabling.  PC1 can see PC3 shares using the Explorer.  PC3 can see PC2 with the Explorer.  With and without the firewall.  PC1 is a "New" PC that has some indications that it might not be New.  It's being replaced.